# Make gedit recognize more encodings

Tags: gedit

I did some research over this issue and realized that everyone was suggesting to use iconv or recode to change the encoding of the file to UTF-8. The thing is that I **do not want to change the encoding** of the file. I just want to use gedit in order to edit the file (my file's encoding is iso-8859-7) and save it using the same original encoding. Is there a way to do that?

I know for a fact that Kate has a menu option that lets you determine the encoding of the file. Even the default text editor of Windows (!!!!!!!!!!), notepad, allows you to select the encoding. I mean, I like having an extensible default text editor and all, but there are some features that are not optional.

Comment: The thing is that this plugin changes the encoding. I do not want to change the encoding :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found `Character Encoding` option on gedit `Save As..` dialog and it seems you have to add your desired encoding. I think setting up `Character Encoding` to `automatically detected` will do what you desire after you add your encoding to the roster.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Or you can use [geany](http://geany.org) for text editing as well which is quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome developers often value simplicity over features, while KDE developers prefer more features even if it make the program unsuitable for 3-year-olds :)

There is an old [ticket](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=342918) requesting this feature, if you have a read you'll see that Gedit has some sort of encoding auto-detection which, unfortunately, is not always perfect. Since 2009 there's a [patch](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=342918#c10) adding Encodings menu though it doesn't look it's going to be accepted. In fact, the 'patch' seems to be a plugin for gedit written in Python - you may see if it's possible to install it, though it may be outdated.

So, if you need this feature - **kate** is a perfectly good replacement for gedit and has many nice features apart from the ability to change document's encoding.